# NullPointerException : println needs a message in android

Tags: android

in my media player i play a song from sdcard. it shows error as NullPointerException : println needs a message  e in android. i tried long time but i do not know the reason .please assist me.

code:

```
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/t1.mp3");
        seek.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);          
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("sdcard-err2:",ex.getMessage());  //  null pointer exception : println needs a message 
    }
```

Log cat:

```
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889):     at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:208)
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889):     at com.seek.bar.media3.onCreate(media3.java:43)
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
     05-16 19:27:54.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6889):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In the catch, use:

```
String err = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":ex.getMessage();
Log.e("sdcard-err2:", err);
```

Passing `null` to the second argument of a  `Log` logging function throws that error, regardless of the source.

Answer (score 82):

For anyone else that gets this, try replacing the lone method call or variable name with "" + varName.

For example,

```
Log.d("LOGCAT", getErrorMsg());
```

becomes

```
Log.d("LOGCAT", "" + getErrorMsg());
```

Comment: But this?? even if we give string into it and which is required parameter type.. Any idea??

Comment: Just the expanded thought. Because getErrorMsg().toString() won't work with null  but the + operator will. :) .
 P.S. Because even I do this ^  .

Comment: Thnx. Good solution!

Answer (score 11):

Maybe there's simply no message attached in exception you're catching. Try `ex.printStackTrace();`
instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have been trying to debug some jni code that was actually working right and your answer allowed me to pinpoint the error to a java method instead. My jni would call a java method and this method was the one with the problem but the exception would be thrown through the jni code and it would be caught by a catch exception with ex.getMessage() which would then throw the "println needs a message". Your simple suggestion allowed me to find the bug!

Comment: @Leco, I am on similar situation as well. I hope the method just accepts empty string and just print nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Another way that can to use is with Log.getStackTraceString(e), example:

```
Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
```

You can read more about that in [Android Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#getStackTraceString(java.lang.Throwable))

Answer (score 3):

**"println needs a megssage"** was a very confusing message to receive (at least for me) when not using the `println(...)` method at all!!!

In my case and for that matter in all cases that generate this type of error there is a constellation you have to watch out for:

```
try{
...
}catch(..){
  // in here there is a reference to the Logger
}
```

Now the problem is that in your `try{...}` block you are using an uninitialized reference or some old instance that now points to `null`

Setup a break-point at the very beginning of your try block and debug your code step by step, you will find that at some point the code will try to access methods of some object that is null.

In this case I tend to blame your *`seek`* object !

Regards.

Comment: This is not a particularly accurate or informative answer - please see the others to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is useful only when you are 100% sure you have tried all the up and down answers related to Log.

For me it was not at all about logs, @Vero's answer helped me to narrow down my problem.

One of my variable inside try catch block was null at some point of time in execution and hence I was getting this exception, to resolve it I just checked null for all the variables inside try catch block and that is it.

Though you should check why that variable is getting null but that is not part of this issue I guess ;)

Resolved.