# Pass Strings through several activities

Tags: android, bundle, android-activity, src

I have my project classes organized in multiple src folders, which have been working just fine until I changed the switch between activities, now incorporating passing of strings to the following activity. I think the problem is related to the class path.

```
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("email", userEmail);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

[EDIT] I realized the problem is not entirely related to the path of the Classes, even though I currently have MeanSelection.class instead of com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection.class. In fact, the problema seems to be related to the bundle. It works when I use it between the Login and Main activities, but not for activities subsequent to the Main one. I have also tried the alternate approach shown below. I have the subsequent activities edited accordingly.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MeanSelection.class);
                intent.putExtra("email", userEmail);
                startActivity(intent);
```

I have looked at my logcat but I can not detect anything useful. I know this works if I comment the putExtra(s) line.

[ANSWER] After seeking through every error line of the logcat and reading your answers, I realized there was a problem with one of the variables written via Log.d. So, the solution was to erase those lines, since they were there just to verify if the variables were rightly picked from the previous activities via the bundle. My conclusion is: from now on, I will not Log the strings passed from one activity to another. I'm not sure if this is really an issue with Android or just one of those things that comes with no feasible explanation, which we all know so well, but as soon as I erased those lines, I had my app up and running.

Comment: What exactly isn't working ? You can start activities from different packages withing your application.

Comment: The app crashes when it should open the second activity. It's the following error that makes me believe this is related to the path: E/AndroidRuntime(7115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fm/com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: It seems this error is not in the code you're showing

Comment: Post the complete activity code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The app crashes when it should open the second activity. It's the following error that makes me believe this is related to the path: "E/AndroidRuntime(7115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fm/com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message"

**println needs a message** has NOTHING to do with activity anything.  Read your logcat!

I get this error when I try to `Log` a null value, i.e.

```
String foo = emptyBundle.getString("barValue");
Log.d(TAG, foo) // error, Log output functions cannot output null values.
Log.d(TAG, "barValue: " + barValue);  // outputs "barValue: null"
```

Make sure whatever you're Logging or System.out.printlning has a value.

Answer (score 1):

If your sending just one string, you shouldn't have to use Bundle.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection.class);
intent.putExtra("com.fm.MainActivity.userEmail", userEmail);
startActivity(intent);
```

Should work fine. I don't really know if that solves your issue, because you never stated what the error message is.

Comment: When putting extra data into an Intent directly, the key should be a fully qualified name (package prefixed).  Bundles don't adhere to this rule.

Comment: @Phix From [Intent.putExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29) documentation: "The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll"".

Comment: @Sergey So it does say that. I will edit my answer above. Learned something new today.

Comment: @Ancantus I mean that Bundle should adhere this rule too.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov, I've heard this too, but I don't see any documentation backup.  Might be a overkill if it's not required/recommended.

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception you get `E/AndroidRuntime(7115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fm/com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` you are getting a NPE in some logging code in your `com.fm.mondev.MeanSelection` activity.

For instance, check this: [NullPointerException : println needs a message in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018633/null-pointer-exception-println-needs-a-message-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

actually, you are gettin erro about:
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

I think you are passing somethin null to println method