# exception when sending message to android using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I follow the tutorial in [this link](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/#comment-13282). I could successfully get the reg id back from Google.
I am using server side script from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
But when I send message from server the app crashes and please find my log here

```
—–
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-GCMIntentService-2]
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:116)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at com.cordova2.gcm.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:63)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:179)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-14 17:36:13.684: E/AndroidRuntime(377): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-14 17:36:13.757: D/DroidGap(377): Paused the application!
——-
```

what may be the reasons for this issue?

Comment: can you show the code of the lines causing the crash?

Comment: I googled the exeption and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018633/null-pointer-exception-println-needs-a-message-in-android

Comment: please find the code  (The editor do not allow me to put all class): package com.cordova2.gcm;
import ........

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

  public static final String ME="GCMReceiver";

  public GCMIntentService() {
    super("GCMIntentService");
  }
  private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

Comment: and more protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      try
      {
        Log.v(ME + ":onMessage extras ", extras.getString("message"));
        JSONObject json;
        json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");
       // My application on my host server sends back to "EXTRAS" variables message and msgcnt
        // Depending on how you build your server app you can specify what variables you want to send

Comment: error occurs on line  " Log.v(ME + ":onMessage extras ", extras.getString("message"));"

Answer (score 1):

It was a mistake with me. the issue was with the variable name of the server script.

```
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}     . The line $message = array("price" => $message); changed to   $message = array("message" => $message); Now I could get the push message on my android phone.
```