# Error in using Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

I am writing a cursor to retrive data from database but when control comes to cursor it is giving message "Println needs message" I am confused can anyone help me in this regard.

code:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TableA extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{


    String Tablename = "Data";
    private String Column1 = "ID";
    private String Column2 = "FirstName";
    private String Column3 = "LastNAme";

    private String C1;
    private String C2;
    private String C3;

    Database rd;
    Cursor c;


    public final String r_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + " (" + Column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " TEXT, " + Column3 + " Text) ";



    public void setcolumn1(String ID1){
        C1=ID1;
        }
    public  int getcolumn1(){
        return Integer.parseInt(C1);
    }
    public void setcolumn2(String rname){
        C2=rname;
        }
    public String getcolumn2(){
        return C2;
    }
    public void setcolumn3(String Lname){
        C3=Lname;
        }
    public String getcolumn3(){
        return C3;
    }

    public ContentValues insertdata(){


        setcolumn1("1");
        setcolumn2("Ravi");
        setcolumn3("Kumar");

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Column1, Integer.valueOf(getcolumn1()));
        cv.put(Column2, getcolumn2());
        cv.put(Column3, getcolumn3());

        android.util.Log.i(Column1, String.valueOf(getcolumn1()));
        android.util.Log.i(Column2, getcolumn2());
        android.util.Log.i(Column3, getcolumn3());

            System.out.println(getcolumn1());
            System.out.println(getcolumn2());
            System.out.println(getcolumn3());



        return cv;          

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {




        c=rd.db.rawQuery("Select * from Data", null);
        if(c!=null){

            if(c.moveToFirst()){

                System.out.println("Column Count is: "+c.getColumnCount());
                System.out.println("Row Count is: "+c.getCount());
            }
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
05-01 15:57:57.247: W/ActivityThread(7163): Application com.example.Datamanager is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-01 15:57:57.287: I/System.out(7163): Sending WAIT chunk
05-01 15:57:57.379: I/dalvikvm(7163): Debugger is active
05-01 15:57:57.537: I/System.out(7163): Debugger has connected
05-01 15:57:57.557: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:57.759: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:58.057: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:58.259: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:58.467: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:58.677: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:58.887: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:59.087: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:59.297: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:59.509: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:59.738: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:57:59.937: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:00.147: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:00.347: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:00.557: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:00.757: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:00.959: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:01.169: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:01.367: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:01.568: I/System.out(7163): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-01 15:58:01.777: I/System.out(7163): debugger has settled (1489)
05-01 15:59:08.807: E/Datamanager(7163): println needs a message
05-01 15:59:11.368: I/Choreographer(7163): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 15:59:11.748: D/gralloc_goldfish(7163): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-01 15:59:12.846: I/Choreographer(7163): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 15:59:21.756: D/dalvikvm(7163): Debugger has detached; object registry had 514 entries
```

Can anyone please guide me how to proceed because message is different as how can cursor need a message to print.

Thanks
Siva

Comment: My guess is that you never write anything to `C1`, `C2` or `C3`. Maybe you should do what is suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10771650/375789).

Comment: Thanks Alexandre.. That solved my problem

Comment: Great! Just added that as an answer to share the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you never set a value to `C1`, `C2` and `C3`.

As [suggested in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771650/375789), try to do it like this:

```
System.out.println("" + getcolumn1());
```