# AsyncTask println needs a message No Exception thrown

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My AsyncTask is logging an error "println needs a message" however no exception is being thrown in my class. The task is started in an Activity which implements a callback interface I wrote called TaskCallback. In the onPostExecute() it calles the callback in the Activity. From this callback, I run another AsyncTask. Below is the code:

```
public class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, File> {

    private static final String IMAGE_DATA_PATH =
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyAppFolder/AppImages/";
    private static final String TAG = "SaveImageTask";

    private TaskCallback mTaskCallback;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public SaveImageTask(TaskCallback taskCallback) {
        mTaskCallback = taskCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog((Context) mTaskCallback);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Saving Image...");
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(byte[]... data) {

        File imageFile = createOutputPictureFile();
        if(imageFile == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0], 0, data[0].length);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(File imageFile) {
        if(mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        if(mTaskCallback != null) {
            mTaskCallback.onTaskComplete(imageFile);
        }
    }

    private File createOutputPictureFile() {
        File imageStorageDirectory = new File(IMAGE_DATA_PATH);

        // If the default save directory doesn't exist, try and create it
        if (!imageStorageDirectory.exists()){
            if (!imageStorageDirectory.mkdirs()){
                //Log.e(TAG, "Required media storage does not exist");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a timestamp and use it as part of the file name
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.UK);
        String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String fileName = "img_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg";

        return new File (imageStorageDirectory, fileName);
    }
}
```

The onTaskComplete(File file) looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onTaskComplete(File file) {
    if(file == null) {
        Util.showToast(this, "Save Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return;
    }
    notifyDeviceOfNewFile(file);

    ProcessImageTask pit = new ProcessImageTask(this);
    pit.execute(file);
}
```

And the error logged is:

```
E/SaveImageTask: println needs a message
```

As it says in the title, no exception is thrown and the code actually does what it is supposed to do. I've narrowed the issue down to this line of code in the callback:

```
pit.execute(file);
```

If I comment out this line the error doesn't appear. I'm a bit stumped on what's going on. If I remove all logging in my SaveImageTask it still appears so something else is logging it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException : println needs a message in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018633/nullpointerexception-println-needs-a-message-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why a exception is not thrown, because you catch it. That is the whole concept about try-catch.

```
 try {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0], 0, data[0].length);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            // normally you do stuff here when it fails.
        }
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, but as I said, if I remove the log, or even change the tag, the same message still appears.

Comment: @mike73 Use `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block to see the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "println needs a message" is what's shown if you pass a `null` to Log.x(). You're probably getting an `IOException` - `e.printstacktrace()` will probably give you a better idea of *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I was being an idiot and the error was from another class which for some reason had the same TAG it was logging with. Thank you for your input and suggestions, an important lesson about copy/pasting code was learned today.