# Check if SMS comes from Specific string of the raw text file

Tags: android, text-files, inputstream, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android app in which i have to check whether the incoming sms contains the word that is defined in my raw folder textfile.
I named the textfile as keywords and it contains 40+ keywords separated by commas.
Now what I want is that when new sms comes and if it contains the keywords that were defined in my textfile then the SMS is saved in listview. I am managed to do that with hardcoded string but I am not been able to do that by reading keywords from text file.
Here is my implementation in broadcast receiver.

```
if (msgBody.contains(readTxt()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from)) {
    screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
}
```

and readtTxt is defined here

```
private String readTxt(){

    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keywords);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try {
      i = inputStream.read();
      while (i != -1) {
          byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
          i = inputStream.read();
      }
      inputStream.close();
    }   
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

But when an SMS Comes and if it contains the keywords specified in textfile the app get force closed and it says

NullPointerException, println needs a message

I am stuck and dont know what to do because the message is also not saving and the app also closed forcefully.

here is my LOGCAT

```
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335): Process: com.tech.tabs, PID:8335
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.tech.spam.SmsReceived:  java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2675)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:175)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:195)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at com.tech.spam.SmsReceived.onReceive(SmsReceived.java:156)
04-18 14:53:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2660)
04-18 14:53:50.981: D/ProgressBar(8610): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0


public class SmsReceived extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;

ArrayList<String> keywordslist = new ArrayList<String>();


@SuppressLint({ "DefaultLocale", "InlinedApi" })
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
LinkedHashMap<String, String> contactNumber = new LinkedHashMap<String,   String>();

DBkeyword screenedKeywordDB = new DBkeyword(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = screenedKeywordDB.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cur1 = db.rawQuery(Constants.readScreenedKeywords, null);
cur1.moveToFirst();
while (!cur1.isAfterLast()) 
{
    keywordslist.add(cur1.getString(0));
    cur1.moveToNext();
}
db.close();

DBTable dbtable = new DBTable(context);
SQLiteDatabase dbrsn = dbtable.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur = dbrsn.rawQuery(Constants.readScreenedNumbers, null);
cur.moveToFirst();
while (!cur.isAfterLast()) 
{
  contactNumber.put(cur.getString(0), cur.getString(1));
  cur.moveToNext();
}
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
  String msg_from;
  if (bundle != null) {
    try {
      boolean keywordPresent = false;
      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

        msg_from = Utilities.extractNumbers(msg_from);
        Long dateLong = msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
        String msgDate = dateLong.toString();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("address", msg_from); 
        values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis()+""); 
        values.put("read", "1"); 
        values.put("type", "1"); 
        values.put("body",msgBody); 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/"); 
        context.getContentResolver().insert(uri,values);

        if (contactExists(context, msg_from))
        {
            /*Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                       null, null, null);
            String contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));*/
            NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconapp);
            notify.setContentTitle(msg_from);
            notify.setContentText(msgBody);
            notify.setAutoCancel(true);
            notify.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notify.setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 2000);
            notify.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            notificationIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intentt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
            notify.setContentIntent(intentt);
            //notify.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 268435456));
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notify.build());

        }

        if (msgBody.contains(readTxt()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from))
        {
            screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
        }

        if (keywordslist != null) {
          for (int i1 = 0; i1 < keywordslist.size(); i1++) {

            String keyword = keywordslist.get(i1);

            if (msgBody.toUpperCase().contains(keyword.toUpperCase()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from)) {

              keywordPresent = true;
              screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
              break;


            }


          }
        }

        if (!keywordPresent) {
          for (String key : contactNumber.keySet()) {

            String msgSender = contactNumber.get(key);
            String extractedContact = Utilities.extractNumbers(key);

            if (msg_from.equalsIgnoreCase(extractedContact)) {
              screenMessage(context, msg_from, msgSender, msgBody, msgDate);
              break;

            }

          }
        }
        dbrsn.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.i("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

}

```
  private String readTxt(){

InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keywords);
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  int i;
  try {
      i = inputStream.read();
      while (i != -1)
      {
          byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
          i = inputStream.read();
      }
      inputStream.close();
  }     
  catch (IOException e) {

      String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":e.getMessage();
      Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);
  }

  return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
```

}

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
Uri.encode(number));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
try {
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
      return true;
   }
} 
finally 
{
    if (cur != null)
   cur.close();
}
return false;
}


public void screenMessage(Context context, String msg_from, String msgSender,
  String msgBody, String msgDate) {
DBsms smsdb = new DBsms(context);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsdb.getWritableDatabase();


String query_insertSMS = "insert into " + "sms" + "(" + "contactnumber" + "," + "contactname" + "," + "message"
    + "," + "date" + ") values (\"" + msg_from.toString() + "\", \"" + msgSender + "\",\"" + msgBody
    + "\",\"" + msgDate + "\")";

dbw.execSQL(query_insertSMS);
smsdb.close();
dbw.close();
abortBroadcast();
```

}

}

Comment: `println needs a message` means your calling `Log.*()` somewhere with a `null` second argument.

Comment: What happens if you ultimately store `String readtxt = readTxt()` at first and use that String in rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException : println needs a message in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018633/nullpointerexception-println-needs-a-message-in-android)

Comment: @MikeM. IF I use hardcode second argument it still not working and app forced close

Comment: @ShreeKrishna i dont understand what u said, i am beginner developer

Comment: @ArslanAli Post the logcat of the error.

Comment: @ArslanAli It would be better if you post your Boradcast receivers codes as well as Error log too.

Comment: @AnupDasari logcat is posted sir

Comment: @MikeM. Posted kindly check

Comment: @MikeM. same result and the app force closed saying null exception

Comment: What if you focus on this line then `Log.i("Exception caught", e.getMessage());`. Changing it to `Log.i("Exception caught", " "+e.getMessage());`

Comment: Change all of your `Log.*()` calls to `e.printStackTrace()`. When you post a stack trace, you need to indicate exactly which line in your code is throwing the Exception, since we don't have your line numbers.

Comment: Yah you can do exactly as @MikeM. told.