# Error in http connection javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: android, ssl

In the below code what I am doing is getting spinner item from web service. And on item select, some process is done.
The problem is that it is not getting data from a server to spinner.

**Frnt_mapActivty1.java**

```
  /*****************************FOR LOCATION FOR**************************************/
//Download JSON file AsyncTask
public class LocationList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;


@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the WorldPopulation Class
        worldlocation = new ArrayList<LocationBeams>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner
        world_locationlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(Wservices.mGetLocationURL);
        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("location");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                LocationBeams worldpop = new LocationBeams();
                worldpop.setTerm_id(jsonobject.optString("term_id"));
                worldpop.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                worldpop.setSlug(jsonobject.optString("slug"));

                worldlocation.add(worldpop);
                world_locationlist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin_location);
        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Frnt_mapActivity1.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,world_locationlist));
        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                       View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                txtlocation.setText(worldlocation.get(position).getSlug());

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()){
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
 Error in http connection javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

 Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
 Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 

 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.towncitycards, PID: 29656
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:334)
    at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity1$LocationList.doInBackground(Frnt_mapActivity1.java:1725)
    at app.towncitycards.activities.Frnt_mapActivity1$LocationList.doInBackground(Frnt_mapActivity1.java:1698)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: e.getMessage() returns empty message

Comment: what can I use instead of `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: @priya see my answer

Comment: use volley library to call webservice so you can solve all issues

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>       at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)

Problem

```
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
```

**e.getMessage()** is null

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value

Check

**e.getMessage()==null**

Try with

```
 if(e.getMessage()==null)
 {
    Log.e("Error", " "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
else
 {
   Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Read **[NullPointerException : println needs a message in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018633/nullpointerexception-println-needs-a-message-in-android)**